# Как уничтожить activity при переходе в другое activity через navigation drawer?

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеется 5 activity и фрагменты. Т.е. в навигации это - к каждой активити привязан фрагмент указанный как стартовый и + дальнейшие фрагменты из которых можно вернуться к стартовому фрагменту, (т.е. 5 navGraph'ов как отдельные ветки).

Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе через Navigation Drawer (боковое меню) из одной activity в другое, предыдущее activity уничтожилось.
Т.е. нужно, чтобы при переходе из "activivty A" в "Activity B" А уничтожилась и при нажатии на кнопку "назад" (уже в В) приложение закрывалось (а не переходило обратно в предыдущее активити).
Как это можно реализовать для 5-ти или более activity на Kotlin'e?

P.S. В данный момент сколько бы раз не сделал переходов между активити через боковое меню, столько же раз приходится нажимать кнопку back (назад).
Рассматривал вариант с флагами, и вариант с указанием закрытия предыдущей активити при старте следующей, правда не понял как реализовать, т.к. новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас довольно сложная система как на мой взгляд, поэтому я напишу как убивать активность при переходе в intent:

```
val msgIntent = Intent(this, MyActivity.class)
startActivity(msgIntent)
finish()
```

при переходе ключевым является:

```
finish()
```

что означает завершение активности после интента. Так же есть возможность использовать флаги для интента:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

вместо `finish()` можно использовать `finishAfterTransition()` - завершить активность после перехода. У вас не получается свернуть приложение кнопкой "Назад" потому что в стеке есть и другие активности, а кнопкой назад вы завершаете текущую, чтобы данной кнопкой свернуть приложение можно использовать такой вариант:

```
val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
startActivity(startMain)
finish()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, немного разобрался с интентами, хоть я и не принял это как решение моей проблемы, но это помогло мне найти решение.
Интенты в большинстве своем используются при каком-либо действии, да ими можно стек регулировать, но опять таки на сколько я понимаю для это нужно какое-либо действие, вроде клика, может и есть интересные решения, но мне копать глубже пока не охото, хотя есть мысли как это можно использовать, ноооо нет... Лучше проще. Еще раз спасибо, это действительно во многом помогло.